# How to type an asynchronous action and functional React component in Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, asynchronous

I have a pretty basic setup. My Functional Component `Images` fires off a data fetching function `fetchImages` using the React hook useEffect. `fetchImages` is setup as an async function as it waits for the promise returned from `imageAction` to resolve before it dispatches this action to my reducer. Likewise, `imageAction` is an async function since it waits for the promise from `imageRequest` to resolve. Unfortunately, I'm getting some compilation errors from Typescript.

The squiggly line under `const Images:` shows this error:

```
src/components/images.tsx(42,7): error TS2322: Type '() => Promise<Element>' is not assignable to type 'FunctionComponent<{}>'.
  Type 'Promise<Element>' is not assignable to type 'ReactElement<any, string | ((props: any) => ReactElement<any, string | any | (new (props: any) =>...'.
    Property 'type' is missing in type 'Promise<Element>'.
```

And the squiggly line under `fetchImages(params, imageDispatch)` shows this error:

```
src/components/images.tsx(49,13): error TS2345: Argument of type '() => Promise<void>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'EffectCallback'.
  Type 'Promise<void>' is not assignable to type 'void | (() => void)'.
    Type 'Promise<void>' is not assignable to type '() => void'.
      Type 'Promise<void>' provides no match for the signature '(): void'.
```

How do I properly type all my functions? Have I setup my async functions correctly? Is there too many chained async/awaits? I'm not sure how to type things when all these async functions return Promises...

```js
import React, { useReducer, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios, { AxiosResponse } from 'axios';
import * as types from '../types';
import * as imageStore from '../reducers/image-reducer';

export type Images = string[];

export interface ImagesPayload {
  images: Images;
}

export interface ImagesAction {
  type: string;
  payload: ImagesPayload;
}

export interface Params {
  page: number;
}

const baseURL = 'http://0.0.0.0:5000/api/v1/';
const api = axios.create({ baseURL });

const imageRequest = async (params: Params): Promise<ImagesPayload> => {
  const response: AxiosResponse<types.ImagesPayload> = await api.get('/images', { params });
  const payload = response.data;
  return payload;
};

const imageAction = async (params: Params): Promise<ImagesAction> => {
  const payload = await imageRequest(params);
  return {
    type: 'LOAD_IMAGES',
    payload,
  };
};

const fetchImages = async (params: Params, dispatch: Function): Promise<void> => {
  dispatch(await imageAction(params));
};

const Images: React.FunctionComponent = async () => {
  const [{ images }, imageDispatch] = useReducer(
    imageStore.reducer,
    imageStore.initialState,
  );
  const size = 'L';
  const params: types.Params = { page: 1, size };
  useEffect(() => fetchImages(params, imageDispatch));
  return (
    <div className="content">
      { images.map((image: string) => <img key={image} className="image" src={image} alt="" />) }
    </div>
  );
};

export default Images;
```

Comment: Function components can't be async as far as I know. The effect on the other hand could be

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in my comment, components can't by async. You need to move your async logic inside the effect:

```
import React, { useReducer, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios, { AxiosResponse } from 'axios';
import * as types from '../types';
import * as imageStore from '../reducers/image-reducer';

export type Images = string[];

export interface ImagesPayload {
  images: Images;
}

export interface ImagesAction {
  type: string;
  payload: ImagesPayload;
}

export interface Params {
  page: number;
}

const baseURL = 'http://0.0.0.0:5000/api/v1/';
const api = axios.create({ baseURL });

const imageRequest = async (params: Params): Promise<ImagesPayload> => {
  const response: AxiosResponse<types.ImagesPayload> = await api.get('/images', { params });
  const payload = response.data;
  return payload;
};

const imageAction = async (params: Params): Promise<ImagesAction> => {
  const payload = await imageRequest(params);
  return {
    type: 'LOAD_IMAGES',
    payload,
  };
};

const fetchImages = async (params: Params, dispatch: Function): Promise<void> => {
  dispatch(await imageAction(params));
};

const Images: React.FunctionComponent = () => {
  const [{ images }, imageDispatch] = useReducer(
    imageStore.reducer,
    imageStore.initialState,
  );
  const size = 'L';
  const params: types.Params = { page: 1, size };
  useEffect(async () => fetchImages(params, imageDispatch));
  return (
    <div className="content">
      { images.map((image: string) => <img key={image} className="image" src={image} alt="" />) }
    </div>
  );
};

export default Images;
```

You should consider passing effect dependencies though as in its current form the effect is executed on every update

Answer (score -1):

Functional components cannot be async.  As soon as you add async to it, it returns a Promise, which React is not expecting.  HOWEVER, if it is actually working, then you can probably just assert that it is a FunctionalComponent...

Instead of

```
const Images: React.FunctionComponent = async () => {
```

You can say

```
const Images = async () => { } as React.FunctionComponent;
```

```
const Images = async () => { } as unknown as React.FunctionComponent;
```

But even if that works, it is not the best implementation.